# Null object reference onReceive BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android, android-intent, camera

I'm using two activities, the main one, and the camera one. In the mainActivity i call **startActivity(new Intent(this, CameraActivity));**

Now, when camera activity starts, the **onCreate()** is:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.camera_preview);
    View myView= (View) findViewById(R.id.camera_previeww);
    myView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);

    cameraID= Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT;
    mCamera=openCamera(cameraID);
    mCamera.startPreview();

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(Tabbed.BROADCAST_ACTION_TABBED);
    LocalBroadcastManager bm = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
    bm.registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, filter);


    // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
    mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
    FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.camera_previeww);
    preview.addView(mPreview);
}
```

The **openCamera(int cameraID)** method is:

```
    public  Camera openCamera(int cameraIDD){
         Camera c=null;
         try{
             c=Camera.open(cameraIDD);
         }catch (Exception e){
             Log.d("Camera Activity", e.getMessage());
         }
          return c;

     }
```

Also I'm using a BroadcastReceiver like:

```
        private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        byte [] data=new byte[3];
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Tabbed.BROADCAST_ACTION_TABBED)) {
            data = intent.getByteArrayExtra(Tabbed.EXTRA_PARAM_BYTE);
        }
        if (data[FINGER]==MIDDLE_FINGER && data[TYPE]==SINGLE_TAP){
            //switchCamera();
            //releaseCamera();
            //mCamera=Camera.open();
        }
        else if (data[FINGER]==MIDDLE_FINGER && data[TYPE]==DOUBLE_TAP){
            // HAVE TO GO BACK
            kill_activity();
        }
        else if (data[FINGER]==INDEX_FINGER && data[TYPE]==SINGLE_TAP){
            mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
        }

    // kill activity

    }
};
```

And some other methods:

```
        @Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    //releaseCamera();              // release the camera immediately on pause event
}

private void releaseCamera(){
    if (mCamera != null){
        mCamera.release();        // release the camera for other applications
        mCamera = null;
    }
}
void kill_activity()
{
    mCamera.stopPreview();
    mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
    releaseCamera();
    finish();
}
```

Here is the crash:

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                           Process: com.etu.goglove, PID: 6008
                                                           java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(android.hardware.Camera$ShutterCallback, android.hardware.Camera$PictureCallback, android.hardware.Camera$PictureCallback)' on a null object reference
                                                               at com.etu.goglove.CameraActivity$2.onReceive(CameraActivity.java:155)
                                                               at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.executePendingBroadcasts(LocalBroadcastManager.java:297)
                                                               at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.access$000(LocalBroadcastManager.java:46)
                                                               at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager$1.handleMessage(LocalBroadcastManager.java:116)
                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

With all this, I'm trying to take a photo when I receive broadcast intents. So, after my activity has started, I open mCamera and when I receive an intent I make the photo or I get back. At the first time, i can take the photo and then I finish my activity. If i try to restart cameraActivity from the mainActivity, calling **startActivity(intent)**,in the **onCreate()** camera is open and it is not null (checked with the debugger), but this time, when I get in the **onReceive()** method, mCamera is always null, so I get a null object reference on mCamera!(when I'm trying to do **mCamera.takePicture()**) don't know how ...

Thanks!

Comment: can to post crash log

Comment: crashes in CameraActivity.java on line 155, check once your code

Comment: @Gautam yes, i know it crashes there. But why? when i get into onCreate() mCamera is not null, then when i get into onReceive(), it is null. I can't understand this ...

Answer (score 0):

```
    private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        byte [] data=new byte[3];
        if (intent!=null && intent.getAction().equals(Tabbed.BROADCAST_ACTION_TABBED)) {
            data = intent.getByteArrayExtra(Tabbed.EXTRA_PARAM_BYTE);

        if (data[FINGER]==MIDDLE_FINGER && data[TYPE]==SINGLE_TAP){
            //switchCamera();
            //releaseCamera();
            //mCamera=Camera.open();
        }
        else if (data[FINGER]==MIDDLE_FINGER && data[TYPE]==DOUBLE_TAP){
            // HAVE TO GO BACK
            kill_activity();
        }
        else if (data[FINGER]==INDEX_FINGER && data[TYPE]==SINGLE_TAP){
            mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
        }
}
    // kill activity

    }
};
```

Comment: what should i understand from this..?

Comment: add intent!=null  in receiver

Comment: Nothing changed

Comment: The intent i get is good, but mCamera turns to null as soons as i get into onReceive method